# form resizing and mazimizing problem

Tags: wpf, vb.net, forms, resize, maximize

my form gets the black effect while resizing or maximizing the form
i want to remove that black screen effect 
can someone help in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have to explain what the black effect is.
I suspect it could be that you make some task in the `OnResize` event in the rendering thread that prevents it from repainting the window. But this is really speculation.

Comment: i am not handling any event.when lets say clicking on maximize button the form does not get painted faster.i can see the delay in painting....so i just want to remove that delay....i am using wpf

Comment: Please describe the content of your window. Estimate the number of elements that have to be displayed. Try to temporarily remove some of them to see if the performances improve.
Otherwise it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: haha....ya this i tried but thats not the problem...my problem is its flickerin a lot n really i cant remove those objects rathr i have created one usercontrol and i am just using that usercontrol and menu only in the window

plz help me .... :(

Comment: You have two solutions: either publish all your code and try to find someone who has time to spend on it, or simplify your problem until it can be reproduced by others. The second way is certainly the best, and chances are that you will solve your problem yourself with this method.